# Consider the function $ \large \ f(x)= \frac{ax^2+k}{bx^2+h} \ $ , Asymptote and Intercept

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider the function $ \large \ f(x)= \frac{ax^2+k}{bx^2+h} \ $ , where $ \ a,b, h, k \ $ are all constants with $ \ a,b >0 \ $ .

Show that-

(i) Discuss about the asymptotes and intercepts of the function above if $ \ h,k >0 \ $ .

(ii) If $ \ k<0 \ \ and \ \ h>0 \ $ , discuss again  the asymptote and intercepts?

**Answer:**

(i)

I have calculated as-

$ y=\frac{a}{b} \ $ is horizontal asymptote.

No vertical asymptote.

For intercept,

set $ x=0 \ $ , then $ \ f(0)=\frac{k}{h} \ $

Set $ \ f(x)=0 \ $ , then $ \ ax^2+k=0 \ \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{\frac{-k}{a}} \ $ , does not exists because $ k>0 \ $

So y-intercept is  $ \frac{k}{h} \ $  but no $ \ x-intercept \ $.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

Comment: What does it mean (ii)? If $k<0$ then the $x$-intercept does exist, while the asymptote is still the same. Sign of $h$ would be important only if $h<0$ because if so we will have two vertical asymptote too

Comment: what about my answer for $ (i) \ $ ?  Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's OK to me

Comment: ok , thank you very much